# Opera speed dial not working in opera 35

Tags: html, browser, opera

Opera speed dial doesn't seems to work although I have a logo.PNG in my root directory. The size of the image is 256 x 160 and I cannot see that in the speed dial. It displays example.com

Comment: just to make it clear, you bookmarked your site in Opera on speed dial? and you can't see your logo on thumbnail? did you choose logo from heart menu? http://prntscr.com/agd9cj

Answer (score 1):

Try [Enable Speed Dial](http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Speed-Dial-in-Opera) **or** try this setting:

1. Go to "Edit" -> "Preferences" -> "Browser".
2. Scroll down to "Advanced settings" and check "Show advanced settings".
3. A "System" section will show up. Uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available".
4. Restart Opera..

Comment: The speed dial is not displaying my logo, otherwise it displays the speed dial and my website shows up as example.com.

Comment: Where is hosted your website?

Comment: August 2019 checking in (Opera 62). My speed dial page was totally blank - no thumbnails, nothing. I could right-click and had the option to add pages to speed dial, but nothing would show up. Tried the steps above and it's working now. Opera icon -> Settings (or push Alt+P), scroll to the bottom, "Show advanced settings," scroll almost to the bottom again, and turn off "Use hardware acceleration when available." Restarted and speed dial is working now.